# Cloudformation features unavailable in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, terraform0.12+

Does anyone know of any AWS Cloudformation features that are currently unsupported by Terraform?

I'm aware of the case of rolling deployments of new instances into an auto-scaling group *Not sure if this has been sorted out!* but I'm curious to know if there might be other AWS-related activities you can carry out with CloudFormation but not Terraform.

Comment: Rollback of failed deployments!

Comment: There are many. Lack of creation policies, lack of replaceupdate policies, lack of IAM support, lack of stack policies, lack of centralized place in AWS to view all resources managed by terraform, lack of B/G deployments for ECS, lack of support for cfn-init, cfn-hup, and more. Are you interested in anything of particular?

Comment: I'm in the process of making a design decision of which infrastructure as code tool to use, hence the question.

Comment: @Hammed I usually recommend using native AWS tools if you know you are going to use AWS only. If not, and your project/work involves working with different cloud providers, then terraform is better.